# A mystery involving matchboxes and lighters

Tags: situation, mystery

There was a family of 4 people . They had a daughter named Rina and his brother's name was Tarun . Everyone knew that their father was a scientist, and is on in doing some experiments all day and night and is trying to invent something , yet it was not known to them what he was trying to invent .

The family had some workers , like the maid , the cook , the watchman , etc .

**Murder/Suicide $1$** :- The family lived happily for a lot of days , but one day turned out to be terrible . The daughter Rina was found dead this morning . Detective Sherlock Holmes was immediately called for the case :-

He found some evidences, and interrogated her mother who was the only one there with her and the $1$st to find her body at the kitchen .

**Evidences** :- Rina's body was found in the kitchen . It was clutched on the ground , with her chin touching a base of the kitchen . On her left-hand was a matchbox and on her right-hand was a matchstick which was burned out . On the stove stood a pressure cooker , which  wasn't lighted up.

**Interrogation** :- On interrogating with her mother , she said, "I was knitting a sweater. I also thought to cook some food in a pressure cooker . When the cook is absent, I usually do the cooking, but I just thought to tell my daughter about it. So I asked my daughter to lit up the pressure cooker in the kitchen. It took a lot of time for her to return , so I thought to check her once in the kitchen, and found her dead."

On interrogating more, Sherlock found that the cook was absent that day, and the maid was cleaning another room, and the watchman was watching the outside gate, the milkman gave $3$ bottles of milk that day, and so on. His brother was watching TV and his father was sleeping in his bed.

Sherlock found the death of Rina to happen at morning. Sherlock also found out that the mother liked to smoke, and she would cook food by herself only and would smoke once every evening and before bed at night.

Sherlock didn't found out any bullet wounds , scratches , etc on her body . Also there was no sight of poison in her body. So he got no idea of the suicide or the murder weapon .
Sherlock couldn't make this out at all, so he waited a little bit more about this case.

**Murder/Suicide 2** :- Their house had a ground outside . Another day turned out to be terrible for them. His brother Tarun was found dead this evening . His body was just lying on the ground . Sherlock Holmes was again called for this case .

**Evidences** :- To his surprise, he found a matchstick burnt out in his right-hand and a matchbox in his left-hand . The exactly same case for Rina but his hands are switched . His body was found lying on the ground . There was also a cigarette in his right-hand . The first to found his body was a neighbour of their family who came to the ground at first .

Sherlock found the matchbox to be the exact same matchbox which Rina had in her hand .

**Interrogation** :- Sherlock now asked all the neighbours of their house and found that everyday they and Tarun would meet in the ground and would do discussions , chats , etc . Most of them would smoke , and Tarun would also like to do smoking . However today Tarun was the $1$st to come in the ground , and on waiting for the other neighbours he probably suicided himself , or get murdered by someone .

On Interrogating with his family members , his mother, crying , said that she was only doing all the housework and is disheartened by seeing all this situations, his father was getting frustrated and furious and was only saying that he was sleeping, as he always liked to sleep. The maid was drying the clothes , the cook was cooking food for them, the milkman gave $3$ bottles of milk today again , and the watchman was guarding the frontgate (the frontgate did not face the ground , so the watchman did not face the ground.)

After hearing all this , Sherlock was totally confused , thinking deeply about the case in his home .
Similarly, Sherlock didn't found out any bullet wounds , scratches , etc on his body too . Also there was no sight of poison in his body. So he again got no idea of the suicide or the murder weapon .

**Murder/Suicide 3** :- Suddenly, the same night, the father was found lying dead in his bed. The mother found him dead , and Sherlock was called again. All thought someone murdered him while he was sleeping .

**Evidence** :- In this time , there was a matchstick burnt out on his right-hand and a lighter on his left hand . Besides him was a letter that read :-

"I always tried and tried, but I never succeeded in doing so. I don't want to live in this world. All my children died watching me. So I don't want to live here and I  am committing suicide. "

After seeing this , Sherlock immediately understood the whole case, what happened and how it stood.

Can you find it? What exactly is this case and what happened then?

Giving you a hint to start with :-

> Hint $1$ :- In every death the thing that was common is a matchstick . Perhaps it could be the murder/suicide weapon , but how can a matchstick kill someone?

Should I give a Hint $2$ ? That will reveal some more information :) . I will start a bounty if I get no answer for this . This is a mystery to think hard !

Here is a Hint $2$ then :-

> Hint $2$ :- Are each of these deaths a suicide ? If it had been a murder , who do you think is the murderer then? Also what exactly do you think the father wanted to say in his letter? It's also possible that someone copied the letter himself and used a fake letter on his death , but it's upto you to think :) .

Comment: This story is actually quite familiar. I think this is the plot of an Indian detective show's episode with the detective's name being changed. is it so @Souradip Das?

Comment: Hey ! I guess you know it . Well let's make some foreigners try it :)

Comment: Hi Souradip - did you mean to give the green checkmark already (usually given to the correct answer) and then also raise a bounty for somebody to provide a correct answer?? Just seems like mixed messages to me... Thanks.

Comment: I gave the green checkmark for it is the only partial answer that has partially answered my question (think about it as the most helpful in finding the solution [it's the best for now, other answers are also awaiting !]) .

Comment: @SouradipDas -- You don't accept an answer unless it's fully correct.

Comment: I dont really like this one.
Rot13: Gurer jrer ab genprf bs cbvfba, lrg gur nafjre fhccbfrqyl pbagnvaf zngpufgvpxf jvgu n zntvpny glcr bs cbvfba sbe juvpu n fvatyr bar vf rabhtu gb xvyy naq vf fgvyy rssrpgvir va na bhgfvqr nern.
Gur sngure jnf n fpvragvfg, abg n zntvpvna.

Comment: It looks like this is a question taken from some other source. For puzzles derived from somewhere else, you must state the place the question came from by our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think *father wanted to murder her wife* maybe because of extra marital affair or money  but there *children got murdered*
>  so because of that **father commited suicide** .

***Reasons*** :

***For  First attempt*** :

> Father knows her ***Wife cooks food on its own*** and Also he might be
>  knowing the ***cook was absent*** that day so he kept the matchstick there
>  he though mother will be cooking but , mother send daughter to lit up
>  the pressure cooker so the attempt was failed and her daughter got
>  murder by accident

***For Second Attempt*** :

> Father was knowing her ***wife like to do smoking in evening*** and
>  before bed time so he might have thought wife will do smoking as usual
>  but may be his son took that matchstick and cigarette and again
>  attempt got failed his son was murder accidently

So , when father saw all his attempt was failed he *committed suicide* and leaves letter that say :

> *I always tried and tried, but I never succeeded in doing so. I don't want to live in this world. All my children died watching me. So I
>  don't want to live here and I am committing suicide*.
>
>  That simply means he tried to kill his wife many times but got failed
>  and in this attempt his children got away from him so he did suicide.

Also , if mother had killed dad blame for his murder will directly go to her she was knowing so she can't killed her husband .

Comment: Hey , excellent answer !! You got it fully correct .

Comment: :) alright nice  but what about this "To his surprise, he found a matchbox burnt out in his right-hand and a matchstick in his left-hand " , matchbox is burnt and this stick is most probably not , it seems to be the same which father used , so how did he burned the matchstick box without using the matchstick in hand

Comment: Aah , why do I make typos , change the "box" with "stick" and vice versa .

Comment: You don't explain *how* the people were murdered or did commit suicide.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe the problem is matchstick, his father was working on it, the burning of the
>  matchstick create some holograph (in the smoke) or intense suffocation which might have
>  given them a heart attack,
>  the last matchstick was the one used by the father when the matchbox got burnt in the
>  Tarun's death case he used the lighter.

A story I think  possible is,

> the death of the Rina and Tarun were accidents and death of father was murder.
>  possible story,

> 1. father was working on matchsticks which no one knew that he was working on it.

> 2. cook was absent, mother said daughter to cook food, due to burning of the matchstick which might have caused suffocation killed her by accident. No one knew it except the father but he could not confront it.

> 3. The same matchbox was removed from Rina by Tarun,

> 4. Tarun is not supposed to do suicide, who will go outside just before meeting his friend to do so, he could have done it somewhere alone and safe.

> 5. Tarun came outside to smoke since we know that the matchbox was burnt except one matchstick, which is not used at all, so the fire must have came not from the box but the cigarette, which was already burnt, someone gave a burning cigarette to his right hand , most probably the suspect could be left-handed(at least smokes with a cigarette in left hand),
> The cigarette caused some spark in the box which burnt the whole box, The suspect must be at some distance by now as he didn't died and witnessed the matchstick killing Tarun and gained the knowledge that the matchstick is the reason of death of Rina and Tarun, which no one but the Scientist can only make.

> only 2 possibilities exist as only two-person know about the matchstick , either the father committed suicide in guilt or the suspect killed him in rage, (most probably murdered).

> 6.  The same suspect in rage might have killed the father, since the suspect is left-handed(or smokes with a cigarette in the left hand thus has a practice of burning the lighter with right hand) he put the lighter in left hand of the father and matchstick in right.

> 7.  There is also a possibility that the father was left-handed and committed suicide due to guilt, mostly not this case as if he loved his children he would have recovered the matchbox just after Rina to save others but he didn't so he didn't cared.

> 8. finally about the note, it either means the person who wrote it either saw
> the deaths or it might mean he assumes himself to be reason for their death.
>  Due to this, I think the mother killed the father, She went to smoke in taruns >!case and gave her cigarette (already burning to him), which he took and died, In rage that the matchbox is the reason and the father was not giving any consideration she killed the father with the last matchstick.

This is all based on my story and might be very much far away from truth, maybe other small details have some meaning like 3 milk of bottle etc =).

TLDR

> I think the mother murdered the fathe , other 2 were accident.

Comment: Partial Answer , but you are correct in the case whatever you have said . In fact there's more info that should get revealed from here .

Comment: @SouradipDas if you like to give a hint 2 as you said , =)

Comment: Well I am giving it , I guess this question did not get that attention , will be good if someone starts a bounty right now

Comment: could you please clear these ,
 1)what is base of kitchen(is she lying upside down) and
2) when rina died , it is written she died in the morning and there is also one line , 
she was found dead last night, are both of  these statements correct.

Comment: aah typo , editing it

Comment: So I read your full answer , why do you think the father was murdered if he was the only one to know about the matchstick? , had he been murdered with the matchstick , the murderer knew about it, but no one even knew what the father was experimenting with.

Comment: yup requires a better solution I guess.

Comment: Znlor gur sngure jnagrq gb zheqre gur zbgure sbe fbzr ernfba? Yvx Vafhenapr be fbzrguvat?